# SQL Transpose Row to Column

Tags: mysql, transpose

I have a SQL query question. My current table look like this :

```
 +--------+------+-----+-----+------+
| hostid | itemname   |  itemvalue |
+--------+------+-----+-----+------+
|   A    |      1     |      10    |
+--------+------+-----+-----+------+
|   B    |      2     |      3     |
+--------+------+-----+-----+------+
```

How would I write a query so that I can get an output like this ?

```
+--------+--
| A   | B |  
+--------+--
|  1  | 2 |
+--------+--
|  10 | 3 |
+--------+--
```

Answer (score 0):

In general what you are seeking is known as a "**pivot**". This however needed a small "trick" - using a `cross join` - to allow movement of 2 columns into 2 rows. Then `max()` and `group by` are used to produce the pivot.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5cef8/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`hostid` varchar(1), `itemname` int, `itemvalue` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`hostid`, `itemname`, `itemvalue`)
VALUES
    ('A', 1, 10),
    ('B', 2, 3)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select a, b
from (
      select 
          max(case
             when n = 1 and hostid = 'A' then itemname 
             when n = 2 and hostid = 'A' then Itemvalue 
          end) A
        ,  max(case
             when n = 1 and hostid = 'B' then itemname 
             when n = 2 and hostid = 'B' then Itemvalue 
          end) b
          , n
      from table1
      cross join (select 1 n union all select 2) n
      group by n
    ) d
;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5cef8/1/0)**:

```
|  a | b |
|----|---|
|  1 | 2 |
| 10 | 3 |
```